# C++ : Assigning 2 constructors with 2 different variables doesn't work

Tags: c++

I wrote 2 contructors in my program with 2 different variables . However when calling them in main() I get an error saying :

```
    main.cpp:23:11: error: no match for call to '(Basis) (const char [5])'
   a("test");
```

This is my program :

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    enum Test{Mo,Di};
    
    class Basis
    {
    public:
      Basis(std::string str) { cout << str; }
      Basis(Test a)
      {
        cout << a;
      }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
      Basis a(Di);
      a("test"); //Error here 
      return 0;

}
```

Shouldn't this be working ? I'm assigning for each constructor its own variable .

Comment: You're looking for a reconstructor.  I mean, *assignment*.  `a = Basis("test");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I guess this here answers my question . Dunno why no one mentioned it .
Just had to add a void operator to my public class

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    enum Test{Mo,Di};
    
    class Basis
    {
    public:
      Basis(Test a)
      {
        cout << a;
      }
      void operator()(std::string str )
      {
        cout << str;
      }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
      Basis a(Di);
      a("test"); 
      return 0;

}
```

This will print

```
1test
```

Comment: I suspect no one mentioned it because it is not a *constructor*, it's a *functor*.

Comment: @Gaston No, it's a completely different thing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know that this is not the same thing but If I want to use the constructor /functor multiple times for different perspectives then it will be possible with the void operator()

Comment: @Gaston The function call operator is not a constructor. The expression `a("test"); ` does not use a constructor in any way. You can never use a constructor more than once.

Answer (score 3):

The line where you have `//Error here` is not calling a constructor (since a is already instantiated).

Maybe you want something like this to create a second instance of Basis (thus calling the constructor you're wanting):

```
int main()
{
  Basis a(Di);
  Basis b("test"); //calls std::string constructor here 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually thought that It was possible to write multiple constructors with just different variables

Answer (score 1):

The class `Basis` and its overloaded constructors are fine. The error is that
the code tries to call the parentheses operator method of the class.
And as there is no such method it thus provides the error you had documented.
Using parentheses to construct an object only works when you are first declaring it.
You can't reconstruct the object the variable is holding, however you can set the variable to a new object of that class. Like [Elijay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641116/eljay) had stated.

```
a = Basis("test"); // Sets the variable
```